# Get Data from different databases on SQL Sever

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have 2 databases on the same server. One called **Clients** and one called **Company**. For both database, it contains information like, company name, address and telephone number. In the Company database, it is possible that the Client database may contain the same information in the Company database. I want to get all the Data from the Company database which have the same telephone number of any data in the Client database. How would I go about doing this??

Thanks

Comment: You need to give us the table structure of both databases, and explicitely state how the telephone numbers are stored and what you really mean by "all the data".

Comment: If the account has access to both databases, and your table keys match, you can join across databases by specifying the fully qualified name (`[Database].[Schema].[Table]`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT co.Name, co.Address, co.Phone, cl.Name, cl.Address, cl.Phone 
FROM Company.dbo.Table co
JOIN Client.dbo.Table cl on cl.Phone = co.Phone
```

Give this a try.

You may have to also make sure they have the same collation. The query may not work if the collation of the databases is different.

Answer (score 1):

Is there only one table that matches in both databases that you are needing to look through?

```
Select comp.*
From Company.dbo.TableName comp
Join Clients.dbo.TableName cl on comp.PhoneNbr = cl.PhoneNbr
```